# Exporting from Principle App; an interactive animation without the need for the Principle App?

Tags: export, principle-app

I came across a very [adorable interactive character animation](http://principletemplates.com/character-animation-dog/) made in Principle app. I realise it might not be the best platform to do something like this in, but since I own Principle and no other animating software I'd like to do it here anyway.

When I'm done, I'd like to show this to the world, preferably *with* interactive features like the demo. I'd like to upload this somewhere and still keep the interactive features, kind of like 'good old' flash did.

How would I best go about this?
Is HTML/CSS the way to go? jQuery? Are there other options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears as though Principle will allow you to save a video file or gif if you record an animation (Of course you lose the interactivity)....

Just hit the record button, in the upper right corner... [image]

Then when you click it again (after interacting a bit with the image), you are presented with save options...

[image]

*(I'm assuming you know the above since you linked to a gif animation)*

It would appear if you want the *interactivity*, you're going to have to **rebuild from scratch** using html, css, svg, canvas, etc. I see no method to export anything in web-ready formats other than .gif. In addition, there appears to be no underlying structure which may be in a usable "starting point" state.

Principle's own docs state that in *all* instances (other than gif or movie) viewing **requires** the Principal Viewer application. And the documentation also states that a user will be presented with a "view in Principle" warning when trying to view anything. There are zero documentation notes regarding exporting or saving to anything other than gif, movie file, or Principle viewer file. I even saved as a Mac app and viewed the internal package contents along with viewing the code structure of the .prd file ... I don't believe the app us set up to render standard cross-browser web pages or markup in any way.